# How can i write text in file in exact way i wrote it in terminal?(with all white spaces preserved)

Tags: c

Lets say i want to write this in terminal

> 

Hello
Im Marjan
I cant think of a way to execute this
Please help

What functions should i use?

Thanks

How do i make it look exactly like this in a text file?
The language im working with is C
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should try and make a question following [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you properly.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sence since whatever you read from the terminal will be in the a text format and can be just written into a file.

Comment: `./prog > output.txt`

Comment: I cant get it to format properly, with white signs etc, its either all in one long string with no white spaces, or every word gets written in new line, i tried with fputs().fprintf() but i cant get it to work the way i want to:(

Comment: @MarjanStojanov `getchar()` and `fputc()` are probably what you want, but you could also use `fgets(buffer, buffer_size, stdin);` and `fputs(buffer, fileptr);`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void output_text_data(FILE *fo){
    enum status {
        OUT, IN
    } st = OUT;

    char buff[128];
    FILE *fi = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    if(fi==NULL) return;//need this c file in same directory

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fi)){
        if(strcmp(buff, "#endif\n") == 0)
            break;
        if(st == IN)
            fputs(buff, fo);
        if(strcmp(buff, "#if LIKE_HERE_DOCUMENT\n") == 0)
            st = IN;
    }
    fclose(fi);
}

int main(void){
    output_text_data(stdout);

    FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    output_text_data(fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

#if LIKE_HERE_DOCUMENT



Hello
Im Marjan
I cant think of a way to execute this
Please help

What functions should i use?

Thanks


#endif
```